# How to use one single command line to show the highest value in the third field

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a text file named file1. It contains three column of data.
How to use one single command line to show the highest value in the third field?

```
111 222 333
555 222 222
444 111 212
222 111 111
```

It tried the following command:

```
cut -f3 file1 | sort -r
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: cut -f3 file1| sort -r

Answer (score 4):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk '{m=$3>m?$3:m}END{print m}' file
```

---

Btw, about the command line you tried, it should be:

```
cut -d' ' -f3 file | sort -nr | head -n1
       |                         |
       |                         +------------ pipe to head to get just the max
       |
       +---------- cut needs a delimiter
```

Comment: hehe, I golfed your awk :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $3}' | sort | tail -1
```

or

```
sort -rk 3 | awk '{print $3;exit}'
```

or

```
awk '$3>a{a=$3}END{print a}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the objective been to print the sorted values in the descending order, I would do something like this

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3];next}
      END{asorti(a);
      printf "Sorted values from col3\n";
      while(NR>0){           #NR or the Number of Records comes handy here
      printf "%d\n",a[NR--]  #awk supports post-fix operations using --,++
      }
   }' yourfile
```

**Output:**

```
Sorted values from col3
333
222
212
111
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
cut -d ' ' -f3 file1 |sort -n |tail -1
```

cut field 3 with space () as delimiter, sort them numerically (`-n` flag), then take the last entry.